# Gestão de permissões usando Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, segurança, autenticação, active-directory

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação ASP.NET C# e neste momento estou no ponto de login que se encontra praticamente terminado.

Estou a utilizar`<authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>`
e um código que permite a aplicação verificar que as credenciais estão corretas.

Falta-me apenas o código que restrinja as permissões a grupos.

Gostava que me indicassem um código simples que me permita basicamente atribuir a permissão de entrar na aplicação apenas as users que estiverem dentro do grupo de AD já existente.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="meudominio\Grupo"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: De que forma você pretende restringir? Cada grupo vai ter acesso a determinado módulo? Ou tem um grupo que pode acessar a aplicação?

Comment: Neste momento quero apenas para acessar a aplicação.

Comment: Mas futuramente através das roles acho que consigo gerir isso de restringir a cada grupo uma função.

Comment: E como você faz a comunicação com o Active Directory? Com alguma lib?

Comment: ` [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool LogonUser(string name, string domain, string pass, int logType, int logpv, ref IntPtr pht);
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IntPtr th = IntPtr.Zero;
            bool log = LogonUser(txt_name.Text, "meudominio" , txt_pass.Text,2,0, ref th);
            if (log)`

Comment: Neste momento estou a usar este código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei por utilizar este código super simples e 100% funcional.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime />

    <authorization>
      <allow roles="dominio\grupo" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para atribuir permissões de forma simples para grupos do AD, você pode incluir as seguintes configurações no Web.Config.
Essa configuração abaixo mostra quais usuários ou grupos permitem acessar a aplicação.

Usuários

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="domainname\user1,domainname\user2,domainname\user3" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Grupos

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="domainname\Managers" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Foi uma pena ter que dar um +1 (estava legal a sua reputação :p). Brincadeira a parte, gostei da resposta simplista.

Comment: Quando se refere as "Managers" refere-se ao nome do grupo certo ?
Desculpem mas sou ainda um "novato" nesta matéria.

Comment: @AndreBrandao Isto mesmo, roles do AD.

Comment: @jbueno kkkkkkk  Obrigado, por me tirar do 666, me salvou..hahahaha !

Comment: Obrigado, vou testar e depois dou feedback.

Comment: @JuniorPorfirio Parecia estar a funcionar mas foi um lapso. Neste momento não faz nada em relação a permissões.

Comment: Vou editar a minha pergunta com o código do meu Web.Config