# Permissões consoante grupos de AD

Tags: c#, asp.net, segurança, login, active-directory

Boas pessoal, como já referi em algumas perguntas estou a desenvolver uma WebAPP de consulta que necessita de ter um login através da rede utilizando os users do Active Directory. O meu objetivo é que exista um grupo e que eu consiga declarar na aplicação que só quem estiver naquele grupo pode ter acesso caso contrário da "Acesso negado".
 Estou há algum tempo parado neste ponto e não há ninguém que me conseguiu ajudar até agora. Já tentei vários métodos mas até ao momento nenhum funciona. Sou novato em ASP.NET e necessitava da vossa ajuda.
Estou a trabalhar utilizando o VS 2012 numa " Empty WebApplication" não num MVC.
Agradecia a vossa ajuda.

Comment: Outra duplicata: [Gestão de permissões usando Active Directory](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182307/18246)

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Percebi que está criando múltiplas perguntas para um mesmo problema, quando isso na verdade não vai lhe ajudar a conseguir uma resposta mais depressa, ao invés disso leia o guia [ask] e o faça um [tour], para aprender um pouco mais sobre o funcionamento do site  para assim aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta.

Comment: São as duas perguntas minhas que não ficaram esclarecidas. Obrigado.

Comment: @jbueno obviamente que gostava de ver a minha questão resolvida mas nas minhas perguntas anteriores não aconteceu. Peço desculpa se estou a ser repetitivo mas necessitava mesmo de ajuda. Agradecido.

Comment: Bom, tente ser mais detalhado, mostrar o código relevante (criar um exemplo mínimo completo e verificável), explicar bem o que está acontecendo. Eu realmente te indico a leitura dos links que postei no comentário anterior. Da forma atual, a única coisa que vai acontecer é ficar publicando perguntas e elas acabarem por ser fechadas.

Comment: Neste momento estou a começar do zero mais uma vez, o que acontecia é que eu colocava o IIS modo de autenção windows no VS a mesma coisa e quando utilizei o código que me foi indicado pelo @JuniorPorfirio simplesmente não fazia nada. Pesquisei bastante até agora e também nada esta a funcionar. Agradecia que se não desse muito trabalho e se não se importa-se me ajuda-se ou então que me explica-se. Como disse ainda sou "novato"

Comment: @jbueno além disso a pergunta que foi indicada como duplicata nem uma resposta tem portanto ...

Comment: Não importa. Primeiro: o fato de as perguntas terem sido feitas por você já caracteriza duplicata. Segundo: de nada vai adiantar você ficar criando perguntas repetidas.

Comment: Então como posso obter uma resposta ?

Comment: [Eu falei sobre isso no comentário acima.](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/182785/permiss%c3%b5es-consoante-grupos-de-ad?noredirect=1#comment378242_182785)

Answer (score 0):

Olá. Você deve utilizar 
as classes de System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement para tal objetivo:

```
// Obtem o contexto do domínio
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAINNAME");

// Busca o usuário. 
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

// Busca o grupo em questão
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

if(user != null)
{
   // Verifica se o usuário está no grupo
   if (user.IsMemberOf(group))
   {
     // Caso positivo, faça alguma coisa
   } 
}
```

http://www.marcioalthmann.net/2014/02/descobrindo-grupos-autorizacao-usuario-dominio/

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/8fd13d9f-a4d4-40ae-997f-eabd5a270af8/como-descobrir-os-usurios-de-um-grupo-do-ad-via-web-part-c?forum=sharepointpt

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029378/how-to-check-if-a-user-belongs-to-an-ad-group

Comment: O primeiro link não está acessível, vou testar e depois se funcionar marco como resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Acabei por utilizar este código super simples e 100% funcional.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime />

    <authorization>
      <allow roles="dominio\grupo" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```